# Django tables 2 - how do i change the queryset of the model i am displaying?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to display all model objects after a get request in a table using django-tables2. It's currently displaying all and I can't figure out how to filter the queryset based on a model pk in my view:

views.py

```
class ViewJob(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = JobResults
    table_class = JobResultsTable

    template_name = 'app/viewjobresults.html'
    paginator_class = LazyPaginator
    table_pagination = {"per_page": 30}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ ViewJob get_context_data request """
        context = super(ViewJob, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        print("ViewJob >get_context_data()")

        context['job_obj'] = Job.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

        # context['object_list'] = context['object_list'].filter(job_id=context['job_obj'].id)

        return context
```

template - app/viewjobresults.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

    {% render_table table %}

{% endblock %}
```

tables.py

```
class JobResultsTable(tables.Table):

    job = tables.Column(
        accessor='job_id.job_name',
        verbose_name='Job')

    results = tables.Column(
        accessor='results',
        verbose_name='Result')

    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "table is-bordered"}
```

Currently the table rendered is ALL Job objects in a queryset. I have the specific job_obj in my view get_context_data() to filter this, but when i filter context['object_list'] (line hashed out) it still displays the entire list of JobResults. How can I change the queryset given to the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `get_table_data()` method to modify your queryset.

```
class ViewJob(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):

    def get_table_data(self):
        job_pk = self.request.GET.get('pk')
        if job_pk:
            return Job.objects.get(pk=job_pk)
        else:
            return Job.objects.all()
```

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/generic-mixins.html